# How can I compute a result and cache it in a class variable?

Tags: python

I'm trying to improve some abandoned code. The code has many similar classes so an easy opportunity is to create a base class and derive from that.

After starting this, I spotted another opportunity within classes to convert what are now instance variables into class variables because they appear not to depend on anything in the instance itself. They should be computed only once per class. There is enough commonality in these computations that pulling some of them into the new base class would be worthwhile.

What I'm looking for is an elegant analog to `__init__` that operates on the class object itself before any instances are created. It's Python so I'm sure there's a way but I can't find it in anything I've read, or maybe I'm not understanding what I've read.

The best I've come up with is creating a class variable in the base class, initialized to None. Then I check it in `__init__`, do the computation only if the class variable isn't set, and set the class variable. All instantiations after use the cached value. Here's a much simplified code snippet.

```
class Base():
  cached_result = None

  def __init__(self):
    if self.__class__.cached_result is None:
      self.result = self.expensive_computation()
      self.__class__.cached_result = self.result
    else:
      self.result = self.__class__.cached_result

  def expensive_computation(self):
    """ In real life, an expensive computation common to all instances. """
    result = 0
    for item in self.class_vars:
      result += item * item
    return result


class Derived1(Base):
  class_vars = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    # Can now use self.result in this instance...
    pass

class Derived2(Base):
  class_vars = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    # Can now use self.result in this instance...
    pass
```

So this is pretty clean and way more efficient than the original (especially with a few hundred thousand instantiations), but I wonder if I'm missing the final nuance that would pull a computation that depends only on class variables out of the instance variable initialization code altogether.

I'm not driving for more efficient or faster. If anything, it would be slower to do this pre-computation for the class if no instance was ever created. I'm just wishing for something more *elegant* than cluttering up `__init__` even in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [class method](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-oop/python-class-methods/) in python3 that does something like this:

```py
class Base():
  cached_result = None

  @classmethod
  def compute_and_cache_result(cls):
    if cls.cached_result is None:
      cls.cached_result = cls.expensive_computation()

  def __init__(self):
    self.result = self.__class__.cached_result

  @classmethod
  def expensive_computation(cls):
    """ In real life, an expensive computation common to all instances. """
    result = 0
    for item in cls.class_vars:
      result += item * item
    return result


class Derived1(Base):
  class_vars = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    # Can now use self.result in this instance...
    pass


class Derived2(Base):
  class_vars = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    # Can now use self.result in this instance...
    pass

Derived1.compute_and_cache_result()
Derived2.compute_and_cache_result()
```

Comment: I see that it looks a little cleaner to mark expensive_computation as a class method but I don't see how the code above works. I can't use the cached result in an instance because it doesn't exist until compute_and_cache_results is executed. It seems I would still need a test in __init__ to invoke the class method.

Comment: While it's true that the cached result does not exist until compute_and_cache_result is executed, once it is executed the cached result is available to all instances of the class and its subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use "lazy" access to your computationally expensive derived data.

Also, when maintaining such information as class data you should bear in mind the potential for concurrent construction of the Base class - for example, if multithreading is in play

Here's an example of the pattern I'd use:

```
from threading import Lock

class Base:
    __foo = None
    __lock = Lock()
    @property
    def foo(self):
        with self.__class__.__lock:
            if self.__class__.__foo is None:
                # do the expensive computation here
                self.__class__.__foo = 99
        return self.__class__.__foo

class Derived(Base):
    ...

print(Derived().foo)
```

**Output:**

```
99
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea. The expensive computation includes access to a remote API so multithreading that would help too.